# Como poder agrandar una sombra con JavaScript.-

Tags: javascript

```js
var Canvas = document.createElement ("canvas");
document.body.appendChild (Canvas);
var Contexto = Canvas.getContext ("2d");
Canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
Canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var Colores = ["red", "blue", "green", "orange", "purple", "lime", "magenta", "brown", "yellow"];
var NumeroParticulas = 25;
var ArrayParticulas = [];
var Cronometro;

class Particulas {
    constructor () {
        this.PosicionHorizontal = (Math.random () * Canvas.width);
        this.PosicionVertical = (Math.random () * Canvas.height);
        this.DireccionHorizontal = (Math.random () * 7) - 3.5;
        this.DireccionVertical = (Math.random () * 7) - 3.5;
        this.Radio = (Math.random () * 10) + 5;
        this.Color = Colores [Math.floor (Math.random () * Colores.length)];
    }
    
    Dibujar () {
        Contexto.beginPath ();
        Contexto.shadowColor = "black";
        Contexto.shadowOffsetX = 15;
        Contexto.shadowOffsetY = 15;
        Contexto.shadowBlur = 10;
        Contexto.fillStyle = this.Color;
        Contexto.arc (this.PosicionHorizontal, this.PosicionVertical, this.Radio, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        Contexto.fill ();
        Contexto.lineWidth = 2;
        Contexto.strokeStyle = "black";
        Contexto.stroke ();
        Contexto.closePath ();
    }
    
    Actualizar () {
        this.PosicionHorizontal = this.PosicionHorizontal + this.DireccionHorizontal;
        this.PosicionVertical = this.PosicionVertical + this.DireccionVertical;
        if (this.PosicionHorizontal + this.Radio > Canvas.width || this.PosicionHorizontal + this.Radio < 0) {
            this.DireccionHorizontal = - this.DireccionHorizontal;
        }
        if (this.PosicionVertical + this.Radio > Canvas.height || this.PosicionVertical + this.Radio < 0) {
            this.DireccionVertical = - this.DireccionVertical;
        }
        this.Dibujar ();
    }
}

function Iniciar () {
    for (let i = 0; i < NumeroParticulas; i++) {
        ArrayParticulas.push (new Particulas ());
    }
}

function Animar () {
    Contexto.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)";
    Contexto.fillRect (0, 0, Canvas.width, Canvas.height);
    for (let i = 0; i < ArrayParticulas.length; i++) {
        ArrayParticulas[i].Actualizar ();
    }
}

function Temporizador () {
    Cronometro = setInterval (Animar, 100);
}

window.addEventListener ("resize", function () {
    Canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    Canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    ArrayParticulas = [];
    Iniciar ();
});

Iniciar ();
Temporizador ();
```

Tengo este código JavaScritp, que basicamente genera unas bolas de colores que se mueven por el canvas y rebotan cuando llegan al final de este.
Le he puesto sombra con JavaScript sin tocar CSS, pero a la hora de hacer la sombra mas grande con la propiedad shadowSpreadRadius, no me lo acepta.
No da error, pero no hace nada.
Soy nuevo en con JavaScript y la verdad es que no se si se pueden modificar todas las propiedades CSS con JavaScript o por el contrario es necesario el uso de este.
Espero vuestra ayuda, muchas gracias.

Comment: Añade el código por favor!

Comment: Ok gracias, lo edite y subió....

Answer (score 2):

Aquí tienes una solución, aunque te advierto que es un poco "chapuza":

Al aumentar `shadowBlur`, aumentas el tamaño de la sombra, pero la difumina. Con tamaños muy grandes, apenas se ve.
Se puede arreglar "acumulando sombras", al dibujar el mismo objeto varias veces, por eso llamo a `Dibujar()` **tres** veces en el siguiente ejemplo.

He aprovechado para "actualizar" un poco tu código: Te recomiendo usar `let` y `const` y no `var` al escribir código Javascript.

**Un último detalle**: Para animar un canvas de manera suave no uses `setInterval`, usa la función específicamente creada para esta funcionalidad: `requestAnimationFrame`. Se llamará automáticamente el número de veces que la frecuencia de tu pantalla requiera: si tu monitor es de 60Hz, se llamará 60 veces por segundo, por ejemplo. Esto aumenta muchísimo la suavidad de la animación.

```js
const Canvas = document.createElement ("canvas");
document.body.appendChild (Canvas);
const Contexto = Canvas.getContext ("2d");
Canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
Canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
const Colores = ["red", "blue", "green", "orange", "purple", "lime", "magenta", "brown", "yellow"];
const NumeroParticulas = 25;
let ArrayParticulas = [];


class Particulas {
    constructor () {
        this.PosicionHorizontal = (Math.random () * Canvas.width);
        this.PosicionVertical = (Math.random () * Canvas.height);
        this.DireccionHorizontal = (Math.random () * 7) - 3.5;
        this.DireccionVertical = (Math.random () * 7) - 3.5;
        this.Radio = (Math.random () * 10) + 5;
        this.Color = Colores [Math.floor (Math.random () * Colores.length)];
    }
    
    Dibujar () {
        Contexto.beginPath ();
        Contexto.shadowColor = "black";
        Contexto.shadowOffsetX = 15;
        Contexto.shadowOffsetY = 15;
        Contexto.shadowBlur = 20;
        Contexto.fillStyle = this.Color;
        Contexto.arc (this.PosicionHorizontal, this.PosicionVertical, this.Radio, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        Contexto.fill ();
        Contexto.lineWidth = 2;
        Contexto.strokeStyle = "black";
        Contexto.stroke ();
        Contexto.closePath ();
    }
    
    Actualizar () {
        this.PosicionHorizontal = this.PosicionHorizontal + this.DireccionHorizontal;
        this.PosicionVertical = this.PosicionVertical + this.DireccionVertical;
        if (this.PosicionHorizontal + this.Radio > Canvas.width || this.PosicionHorizontal + this.Radio < 0) {
            this.DireccionHorizontal = - this.DireccionHorizontal;
        }
        if (this.PosicionVertical + this.Radio > Canvas.height || this.PosicionVertical + this.Radio < 0) {
            this.DireccionVertical = - this.DireccionVertical;
        }
        this.Dibujar();
        this.Dibujar();
        this.Dibujar();
    }
}

function Iniciar () {
    for (let i = 0; i < NumeroParticulas; i++) {
        ArrayParticulas.push (new Particulas ());
    }
}

function Animar () {
    Contexto.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)";
    Contexto.fillRect (0, 0, Canvas.width, Canvas.height);
    for (let i = 0; i < ArrayParticulas.length; i++) {
        ArrayParticulas[i].Actualizar ();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(Animar)
}

window.addEventListener ("resize", function () {
    Canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    Canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    ArrayParticulas = [];
    Iniciar ();
});

Iniciar ();
Animar();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Tendré en cuenta los consejos